# How to add two additional monitors to laptop via USB or HDMI?

Tags: windows, laptop, multiple-monitors

I have an Acer 15 V Nitro with 3 USB ports and 1 HDMI port. I would like to, if possible, add two additional monitors that would each function as a separate screen and have the laptop monitor working as well at the same time.

Is there any way that this can be done or am I limited to one external monitor due to one HDMI output?

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use a USB3 "docking station" such as this which will provide an additional monitor output, but obviously leave you with one less USB3 port and perhaps require the docking station to be plugged into the mains.

This may not be the best on the market, it was just the first example I found from searching:

[USB3 Docking station example](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Plugable-Universal-DisplayLink-SuperSpeed-High-Speed/dp/B00ATU4PFM)

Comment: This is basically what I do. I use my laptop's built in display, its external monitor port, and a DVI port on a USB3 docking station. I would just warn you that some docking stations have two video ports but have resolution limitations if you use both at once.